# Moving legend items up and down in QGIS

Tags: qgis, vector, style, legend

How can I change sort order in layer properties styles tab? The only way I've found is to change their labels and order by it.

Comment: Which renderer are you using? The only one which allows to change the order is the rule-based renderer - if I remember correctly. The others are sorted by ascending numeric value or alphabetically.